# Unable to boot into windows after installing Ubuntu on a second HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I have windows 10 installed on a SSD in my computer. I installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS onto an empty SATA drive. When I select windows from the GRUB boot list, appears as "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdc1), there is an error message  saying the hardware has changed and it restarts.

When I am in ubuntu I am able to see my SSD with all of my files in the files explorer it is listed as /dev/sda2

I have attempted to use Boot repair with no success.

The log can be found here.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PwNMjGcXkV/

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am just creating a windows 10 usb from my old laptop, i have a feeling I may need it!

Here is the error message I am getting

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. to fix the problem:
1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart the computer
2. Choose your language settings then click next
3. click repair your computer

File : \EFI\Microsoft\boot\BCD
Status: 0xc0000225
Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains Errors
```

Thanks again

Comment: It seems that Grub is doing it's job, that is, it is chainloading the Windows Bootloader but the latter is complaining about something. Is secure boot enabled?

Comment: Secure boot was not enabled. I have enabled it and I have the same error message as before. I am going to post a pic of it in the original question, scratch that I do not have the reputation

Comment: Unusual to see ESP - efi system partition on one drive, but Windows install on another drive. Grub sees the /EFI/Microsoft files so adds a UEFI boot entry. But you do not have a Windows UEFI boot entry in your System as if Windows was not installed in UEFI boot mode or drive disconnected. But its all Windows issues which you can only repair with a Windows repair disk.

Comment: The windows 10 bootable USB had no luck with any of the various repair options, I am about to attempt the rescatux bootable

Comment: Rescatux will not repair what Windows Media couldn't? You may have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I can confirm that is the case with rescatux. :(

Answer (score 0):

This happens when using two disks instead of just partitioning the drive Windows is on. Or, this can be cause by Grub not identifying the drive Windows is on. Your best option should be reinstalling Ubuntu on the main drive and partitioning it from windows.